# How to create a variable of type poco::Date::Date and add a particular date?

Tags: c++, eclipse, date, poco, poco-libraries

How can I create a variable of type "poco::Data::Date" using poco library and add a particular date like 18/7/2019 in it?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show a [mcve] of your attempt? How does your attempt work or not work? What's happening when you build or run it? What's supposed to happen? Perhaps it's time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a constructor that takes year, month, day.

```
Poco::Data::Date birthDate(2019, 7, 18); // I am less than one year old
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions you can also use `Poco::DateTime` and initialize with time types as well as date types, down to microsecond resolution.

```
Poco::DateTime epoch(
    1970, // year
    1,    // month
    1,    // day
    0,    // hour (24-hour format)
    0,    // minute
    0,    // second
    0,    // millisecond (0-999)
    0     // microsecond (0-999)
);
```